# Versions Rotation for AWS S3 Object

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is it possible to organize AWS S3 Object versions rotation just on the configuration level and not over api calls to keep only N last versions of bucket or last Max Age ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a bucket lifecycle configuration to delete versions older than N days. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/how-to-set-lifecycle-configuration-intro.html

You cannot do it for the last N versions without writing custom code.